# How to enable two way sync between two Gmail mails?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, synchronization

I have two Gmail accounts, one is personal, the other is business. I have enabled forwarding on the business one, so I get those mails to my personal email account. Sometimes I delete some e-mails from my personal account which have been forwarded from the business account, but they are not deleted from the business account. I want the actions I take in my personal mail to be synced to my business account. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't sync between accounts.  Sync works between an e-mail client on your computer or mobile device and the account on the server (using IMAP).  But forwarding or POP fetching can not sync between server accounts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So this means there is no workaround for this ?

Answer (score 0):

This Chrome extension may work for you: [Gmail Label and Email Sharing](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail-label-and-email-sha/pmmaemmobdmccnfepmkckendmealjapo)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, man. This is a pretty old thread and I wonder how you stumbled upon it)) I checked out the extension you shared and it seems pretty solid, thanks. But I think removing an e-mail from a label won't delete it from the other party's email as well, just remove it from the label, or will it? Have you tried this extension yourself?

Comment: The fix I used was I set my old business e-mail to forward all its received mails to my new personal e-mail without leaving a copy. Now the old e-mail's inbox is always empty and I receive everything in my new e-mail.